# Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, bots

Thanks for taking a look at my questions.

The exception of the application exactly as the title.

It was deployed at the AWS server and was integrating with Skype.

The `Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException` did not happen when I'm testing my application on local with bot emulator.

It happens only when on Skype.

Env:

- Microsoft.Bot.Builder 4.2.2
- Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis 4.2.2
- Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA 4.2.2
- Microsoft.Bot.Connector 4.2.2

```
Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Did anyone know possible reasons of this bug?

Again, thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the message that I sent, it contains HTML tags.
So that may crash the application.

Comment: I am getting same exception/error message, but i am not sending any HTML tags